# What is a good way to handle user-generated page structure using the Play framework?

Tags: playframework

I am trying to build a web application where the user can select and define a web-page's content through the use of some predefined UI components (without exposing any HTML to the users).

Since I'm new to Play framework, I need some good practices to store the (component-based) content of this web page "*the Play way*". Basically I can think of two approaches:

- I can define a page-content definition model that will store the user's creation; and then produce the live page by a smart template mechanism based on the info in this model.
- or, I can convert and store the page-content directly as a template (play template) on the filesytem. But then re-editing of a previously generated content will be difficult to handle I think.
- or, I can use both: the model for the editing and updating, the template to store and display.

Do you propose any one of them, or would another approach be more practical/right for a Play application?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Play! way would be to define all your entities as part of your model and store them in a database. This way you can make the best use of the integrated jpa features which come bundled with Play!.
You could define your html components as Models which are associated with a particular user/site and keep them updated on the db.

```
public class User extends Model {

   @OneToMany
   List<HtmlComponent> components;
}
```

I suggest you go through the [jpa](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/jpa) section and the [tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/home#guide) if you need a better idea of how Play! works.

Personally I would seldomely use the filesystem for anything else than properties and configuration.

Comment: Thanks for answering my first question here :). So the preferred way is to construct my own components and store them in some kind of PageDesign class. Can you tell me one more thing about the solution: I plan to use different tags (groovy tags in *.html) for different component types. Is it a viable solution in this case?

Comment: My first thoughts would be to create your a Model around your requirements (HtmlComponent, HtmlTable...), which will be the holders of the properties that the user defines. Each component can then be rendered as a html tags (good for reuse) where attributes can be constructed dynamically. If you are a bit unsure try it with a simple case. One of the great thing about play is that you can prototype very quickly to find out if your approach feels correct. Good luck.